# Google SignIn complete vs manual app switch

Tags: ios, google-signin

When using `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = NO` how can I tell the difference between the user completing the Google SignIn process or manually switching back to my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user completed google sign in (successfully or not) GIDSignInDelegate method `- (void)signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:` will be called. If its not called, then probably user just returned manually...   Also, you can check in your app delegate: google sign in will return to your app by using the url scheme, as a result this methos will be called: `application:openUrl:sourceApplication:annotation`